# Is there a way to install leaflet search plugin without using npm?

Tags: leaflet, search, node-js

I am not familiar with Node.js or npm at all, but my IT has told me node.js/npm is not compatible with our IIS, and the only search plugins to add on to leaflet are using npm to install them.

I did a search here and found this solution without npm - leaflet-control-geocoder, but it searches address databases such as google or bing, not the geojson data I have plugged into my map that I need to be able to search.

So my question is, is there a way to use the Leaflet Search plugin or leaflet-fusesearch plugin without using npm to install it?

Comment: Small update -  I checked with my own personal hosting company I use, thinking I could just move the project there, however they strictly forbid installing Node.js on a shared server.

Comment: *node.js* and *npm* work just fine on Windows Server; *npm* will need proxy permissions, though, and *node.js* the *iis-node* extension to work with the web services. *Leaflet Search* is available as *.js* files in the [github dist](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search/tree/master/dist).

Comment: most plugins have a download button and don't require npm, npm just makes it easier.

Comment: Ahhh so you are saying I can just use the .js file just like I do other javascript files without any install process. - Since I am new to javascript just one more question then. If I use the files straight from git hub do I need all the other files that come with it or just the js files?

Comment: @eric47905 You might need the CSS, and Image files as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to use the [leaflet-search](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search) plugin, without using NPM.
This is possible, using these steps:

1. Go to https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search
2. Click on the `Clone or download` button, and download as Zip
3. Unzip the downloaded file.
4. Copy the `dist` & the `images` folder to your application.
5. In your Application's HTML file, add links to the CSS and JS file which are present in the `dist` folder (i.e. `leaflet-search.min.css` & `leaflet-search.min.js`).
6. You should now be able to access the `L.Control.Search` object in your JavaScript code.